# How can I sort and find sum with a formula in Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to remove the repeating **account number**s in **Column B** and find the sum of respective account number's amount in column D.
Is there any formula or way to do so ? I have attached image with this link.

[image]

Comment: What you describe is called a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>Excel365</kbd> you can do it very easily. As per my below screenshot put following formula to <kbd>E2</kbd> cell to get unique AC No.

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A21)
```

Then to get sum use below formula to <kbd>F2</kbd> cell.

```
=SUMIF(A2:A21,E2#,C2:C21)
```

[image]